# If/Then Statement for ColdFusion with negative numbers

Tags: coldfusion, if-statement

I am trying to create a workaround on our website.  I need to say if the shipping charge from UPS + the oversized charge we enter per product equal less than 1 (0 or a negative number) the shipping charge should be 0.

Trying to create a work around to do free shipping by product.

The problem is I don't know ColdFusion.  Our system does not have an option for free shipping on the product level.  I tested adding  a negative amount in the field for upcharge on oversized items.  This worked except that if the shipping that was returned was negative it deducted that amount from the sale.  Example widget $10 shipping $8.50 and oversized charge was set at -10 the sales was for $8.50.  I need to set the negative amount high enough that it covers the range of ground shipping charges, so I need to code the charge can never be less than 0.  Hope this makes more sense.

Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question with a) the code you have tried and b) a description of what it is doing wrong? Because this should be quite simple. But perhaps there is more going on than described above ..?

Comment: "gimme-teh-codez" questions don't do well here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking.  How to write the if statement in ColdFusion?

```
<cfif (UPSCharge + OversizeCharge) GT 0>
    <!--- add shipping charge --->
<cfelse>
    <!--- free shipping --->
</cfif>
```

Comment: for free shipping can we just put 0 instead of free shipping?

Comment: Yes, sorry, you can do whatever you need to in those `<!--- comment --->` blocks.  Those are comments in ColdFusion.  You can set a variable to 0 or display 0 or whatever.

Comment: Just to clarify one more this the UPSCharge and OversizedCharge can be changed to match our fields correct?  I'm not 100% sure what our fields are.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, I just added those as placeholders based on your question.  You can substitute your fields/variables there.  It would help if you shared some of the code with us by editing your question.  Then we could answer more specifically.

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
max( 0, (upsCharge + oversizedCharge) )
```